# Looking for parse assistance

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

This is the view from my browser:

```
{
    "data": {
        "request": [{
            "query": "Lat 41.85 and Lon -87.65",
            "type": "LatLon"
        }],
        "time_zone": [{
            "localtime": "2012-02-14 16:05",
            "utcOffset": "-6.0"
        }]
    }
}
```

Now, I am using this code to parse it:

```
function getTimeZone(latlong) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/tz.ashx?key=[removed]&q=" + latlong + "&format=json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
                console.log(parsed_json.time_zone.utcOffset);
                return parsed_json.time_zone.utcOffset;
            },
            error: function (parsed_json) {
                //console.log("Error: " + parsed_json);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Every time I run the code, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'utcOffset' of undefined
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

View of the data being displayed to the console (only copied the part I'm interested in):

```
Result:
  Object
    data: Object
      request: Array[1]
        time_zone: Array[1]
          0: Object
            localtime: "2012-02-14 16:46"
            utcOffset: "-6.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are two issues:

1) to access the content, you need:

parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset;

2) This is a bit more complex - you are using an asynchronous ajax callback - success() is not being called before your program finishes sending the ajax request and returns, and it does not return its results to the parent method.

The basically can't do it the way you want to, unless you use a synchronous fetch (a bad idea, since it'll lock up your browser until the response arrives).

Instead, take a callback parameter, which will be a function, as a parameter to your function, and call that with the result once it arrives:

i.e.

```
function getTimeZone(latlong, callback) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/tz.ashx?key=[removed]&q=" + latlong + "&format=json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (parsed_json) {
                console.log(parsed_json.time_zone.utcOffset);
                callback(latlong, parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset);
            },
            error: function (parsed_json) {
                //console.log("Error: " + parsed_json);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then to use it:

```
getTimeZone(myLatLong, function(latLong, utcOffset) {
   // ... do something with utcOffset here ...
});
```

Comment: Result: 
Object
data: Object
request: Array[1]
time_zone: Array[1]
0: Object
localtime: "2012-02-14 16:39"
utcOffset: "-6.0"

Looks like it's receiving the right data.

Comment: In Chrome/FF+Firebug you get a nice nested tree display in the JS console, so you can browse the object and get a better idea of how it is structured.

Comment: What I posted was what was displayed by Chrome's console.

Comment: Then: return parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset should work

Comment: Nope, its just telling you that its a 1 length array, try adding: console.log("%o", parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset);  That should show the utc string, demonstrating that its navigating the json hierarchy

Comment: I'm not understanding how to use the second code.  How does it fire the first one and make sure everything is timed right?

Comment: basically you call getTimeZone, passing it a function, getTimeZone calls $.ajax, which sends a request to the server for the info, when that returns, $.ajax calls the success() method you pass it, which then calls your callback(), so basically whatever you pass is only invoked once the information is available.

Comment: So, code section 1 and code section 2 are the same function?  I was reading it as two separate functions, hence my confusion.

Comment: Well not quite - section 1 defines your fetch mechanism, section 2 is calling that mechanism, and telling it what to do with the data once it has received it (by passing a function to be called)

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
return parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset;
```

You have to look carefully at the returned JSON structure.  It helps to break it up into separate lines and indent to reflect the nesting.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help.  The reason I didn't add the [0] was I'm not doing a loop.  Does that matter?

Not sure how to break it up, as that's the JSON I'm getting back from the provider, nothing I can edit.

Comment: Its because the 'time_zone' element is returned as a numerically indexed array, so you need the [0] to select the first element from it - I assume it means the provider could provider more than one timezone in the response, but if you just want the first, that should work fine.

Comment: Is there a way to find the data type of one of the values?

Comment: Well, you can use the JavaScript `typeof` operator. Getting that information in JavaScript can be a little frustrating; if you have some specific need to figure something out, it'd probably be a good idea to post a separate question on that topic.

Comment: It looks like a timing issue instead of a type mismatch...now to figure out how to use callback's properly...

Answer (score 0):

should it be `parsed_json.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to help.  The reason I didn't add the [0] was I'm not doing a loop.  Does that matter?

Comment: the value for the timezone is an array of objects, in your example only one object, so its index is 0 and should be specified